# How to find previous and next rows in dataframe for a datetime value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing events with a datetime column. Now I want to find for a specific datetime value the previous and the next event rows. Is there an efficient way to do this?

My dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
       Datetime           Event    ...
0    2019-04-01 00:00:00  x        ...
1    2019-04-01 07:16:54  y
2    2019-04-01 07:17:22  z
3    2019-04-01 07:18:31  a
4    2019-04-01 07:22:23  b
5    2019-04-01 07:23:24  c..
```

What I've tried is this:

```
time = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-01 07:20:02')
prev_row = df[df['Datetime'] < time].tail(1)
next_row = df[df['Datetime'] > time].head(1)
```

This will get me the previous and next rows, but I was wandering if there is a more efficient way to do this (something like `.between()`, but the for around...)

Comment: Assuming `df` is sorted by the `Datetime` column, I believe your solution is as efficient as it gets.

Comment: It is sorted indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `searchsorted`

```
s=np.searchsorted(df.Datetime,time)
```

Then

```
df.iloc[[s-1,s],:]
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for what I was looking for!

Comment: @NielsHenkens please make sure you do not have exact match,  if so , you need add `np.searchsorted(df.Datetime[df.Datetime!=time],time)`

Comment: Thanks for the time. My `time` values are actually in milliseconds and the `df['Datetime']` in seconds. So the chance of them being exactly the same is next to none.

Comment: @NielsHenkens then you should be worry free about above code

Comment: This code fails if time > last df.Datetime, or < first df.Datetime